# d3js: Apply animation together on bubbles and texts

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a bubble cart that contains circles and some text. On inspecting the graph, I get something like this:

[image: inspect].

The problem is that the animation that I have applied work only on the circles. I want to somehow group the circles and texts together and then apply the animation on each group. 
Like I have specified, 2 events: mouseover and mouseout. I want to apply them togeher on the circle and the text inside the circle.

My script is as follows:

```
var margin = 40,
width = 600,
height = 400;

var data = [{"admit_probability":54,"rank":20, "c":12},
            {"admit_probability":79,"rank":111, "c":9},
            {"admit_probability":70,"rank":68, "c":6},
            {"admit_probability":12,"rank":1, "c":20},
            {"admit_probability":197,"rank":87, "c":10}];

var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(
                    d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.admit_probability; })
                )
              .nice() 
              .range([0, width]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.rank; }))
              .nice()
              .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

var svg = d3.select('.chart')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'chart')
                .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
                .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .insert("circle")
   .attr("cx", width / 2)
   .attr("cy", height / 2)
   .attr("opacity", 0.3)
   .attr("r", 20)
   .style("fill", "blue")
   .on('mouseover', function (d, i) { 
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("r", 32)
        .style("fill", "orange");
      })
   .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
        fadeOut();
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return xscale(+d.admit_probability); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return yscale(+d.rank); });
   // .ease("elastic");

var text = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text');

var textLabels = text
        .attr("x", function (d) { return xscale(+d.admit_probability); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(+d.rank); })
        .text("Hi")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "red");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Average Acceptance");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - margin)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Rank");

function fadeOut() {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", 0.3)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("fill", "blue");
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

An easy solution is appending `<g>` elements to hold both texts and circles:

```
var group = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

group.append("circle")
    //etc...

group.append("text")
    //etc...
```

And then add the event listener to the groups, selecting both texts and circles:

```
group.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).select("circle")
        //etc...

    d3.select(this).select("text")
        /etc...
})
```

Here is your fiddle with those changes: https://jsfiddle.net/p5f0eey1/

**Solution 2:**

A second solution doesn't involve any group. This is the problem: when you want to apply the same transition or the same property to a group of elements, people immediately think *"I'll put them in a group element"*. The problem is that creating more and more SVG elements can slow down your page. On the other hand, the script can run really fast these days. So, you can rely on the script to select the text you want, adding the event listener just to the circle.

Since both circles and texts have the same data, you can get the correct text inside the event handler for the circle:

```
circles.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this)
        .attr("r", 32)
        .style("fill", "orange");

    texts.filter(function(e) {
        return e.rank === d.rank;
    }).attr("font-size", "20px")
})
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mtjoxp3a/